# Ruby 2.4.1 Can't read special characters from stdin

Tags: ruby

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2

```
C:\Users\administrador>ruby -v
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x64-mingw32]

C:\Users\administrador>irb
irb(main):001:0> test = gets
testing special char áéíóú
=> "testing special char \xA0\x82\xA1\xA2\xA3\n"
irb(main):002:0> puts test
testing special char ?????
=> nil
irb(main):003:0>
```

It used to work on previous versions of Ruby. What changed?

Comment: It looks like Ruby is reading the input just fine, just your terminal is configured with the wrong character encoding.

Comment: Agree with @JörgWMittag. Just tested your code and it works

Answer (score 2):

change the irb encoding from utf-8 to someother encoding,
my code page default value is 437 and for the irb command it uses the encoding as IBM437[which is working fine]
but when i changed the encoding to utf-8 the result came as u mentioned
hence change the irb encoding

[image]

Comment: It worked when I started Ruby using CP850 (irb -ECP850) which is my terminal default encoding. If I force it to be IBM437 it doesn't work. Thank you! During ruby installation I marked "Use UTF-8 as default external encoding". I shouldn't have done that.

Comment: Yes  we need to change from utf-8 to other encoding, Thanks

Comment: Actually, it is still not working. Even after reinstalling Ruby:
http://imgur.com/a/HKbyJ

Comment: Finally !!! after going through the files of init.rb and locale.rb [no issues with version 2.4.1] , Able to recreate the scenario what u have experienced, here we have to make sure that uninstalling was successful . It worked !!! Thanks and please add irb tag to the question.

Comment: Installation Default UTF-8 VS without it
on left [while installing marking the default UTF-8 box]
and on right [without marking]http://imgur.com/a/sdT4o

Comment: It worked now! I did a clean uninstall and now, after a fresh install, it is working. RUBYOPT was in registry.

Comment: Nope... again... Sorry... Still not working.It is weird. After I install Ruby it works fine until I log out and log in. Then the issue comes back

Comment: Now, it is working because I manually added a Environment variable RUBYOPT as "-ECP850"

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I started Ruby using CP850 (irb -ECP850) which is my terminal default encoding. If I force it to be IBM437 it doesn't work. Thank you! During ruby installation I marked "Use UTF-8 as default external encoding". I shouldn't have done that.